# NM applet dropdown options not working

Tags: network-manager

I recently realized the dropdown options from my nm-applet are no longer working.
But I can still control the network configuration by going through the dash.

This happened very recently. I only realized this before a week. I guess some recent update screwed it up.

I have these related packages installed

- network-manager-gnome       0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2
- libnm-gtk0                  0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2
- network-manager             0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1

Any help would be great.

Comment: i've encountered that too. try to restart the applet. `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet stops responding after a while. [It's a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/930563). Network manager is fine.

Kill and (re)start the nm-applet, you don't even need root access:

```
killall nm-applet
```

then alt+f2 and start nm-applet. It should be working again fine for a while.

Comment: To everyone who is affected by this bug: please go to launchpad to view the bug, log in and click the green text *Does this bug affect you?* at the top of the bug report and indicate that you are affected. The bug has been open for a year but nothing is happening as it is classified as "Low" importance.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
nm-applet
```

If you see the icon. It works by nm-applet command.

So do this,

> start->Startup Applications Preferences->add->command : nm-applet ->
>   add->close.
>
> restart (pc)

Now you can see the icon (all/next restart).